# <!WHATVER!> syntax in Kotlin? (Angle brackets wrapping exclamation points)

Tags: kotlin, syntax

I saw this syntax I'm not familiar with in the Kotlin compiler test suite.

```
// !DIAGNOSTICS: +UNUSED_LAMBDA_EXPRESSION, +UNUSED_VARIABLE

fun unusedLiteral(){
    <!UNUSED_LAMBDA_EXPRESSION!>{ ->
        val <!UNUSED_VARIABLE!>i<!> = 1
    }<!>
}
```

What does `<!UNUSED_LAMBDA_EXPRESSION!>`...`<!>` mean?

Found in [`unusedLiteral.kt`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/testData/diagnostics/tests/functionLiterals/unusedLiteral.kt)

The term `UNUSED_LAMBDA_EXPRESSION` is declared in [Errors.kt](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/Errors.java) to be:

```
DiagnosticFactory0<KtLambdaExpression> UNUSED_LAMBDA_EXPRESSION = DiagnosticFactory0.create(WARNING);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is not valid Kotlin. It is only used in the test data files of Kotlin's test pipeline. That is, only the test runners recognises this syntax, not the Kotlin compiler. Specifically, the `<!DIAGNOSTIC_NAME!>foo<!>` syntax denotes a *handler*. Handlers do checks on things, or output information to a file. In this case, this syntax checks that there is indeed the specified diagnostic being emitted at that point in the file.

Also note that the `// !DIAGNOSTICS` comment at the top is not just a comment. It denotes a *directive*. Directives are like the options for running the test.

I highly recommend you read [compiler/testData/diagnostics/ReadMe.md](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/testData/diagnostics/ReadMe.md), which explains how diagnostic tests work specifically, and if you're really interested in this stuff, check out [compiler/test-infrastructure/ReadMe.md](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/test-infrastructure/ReadMe.md) too, which tells you all about how the whole test pipeline works in general.

Comment: Awesome detailed response. Thanks for both links!! I'm always interested in how everything works. :)